# How to get weeknumber of colum date starting from Monday in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create a new column called weeknumber from a date column. The weeknumber should start from Monday. However i am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

Below is the data and line of code:

```
date={'Date':['5/27/2020','4/27/2020','3/27/2020','2/27/2020','1/27/2020','6/27/2020']}
df=pd.DataFrame(date,columns=['Date'])

df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df['week_no']=df['Date'].strftime("%V")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `dt` before `strftime()`.

```
df['week_no'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime("%V")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        Date week_no
0 2020-05-27      22
1 2020-04-27      18
2 2020-03-27      13
3 2020-02-27      09
4 2020-01-27      05
5 2020-06-27      26
```

****EDIT****:

Declare a function that adds 1 to each value of the `dataframe`. This will match your cycle. Using `%u` matches Monday with 1 so all that needs to be done is to add 1 to the values that come from `%u`

```
def construct_week_column(date_column):
    data = [(int(date.strftime("%u")) + 1) for date in date_column]
    return data

df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['week_no'] = construct_week_column(df['Date'])
```

Comment: Regarding the question on "Monday", in excel we have formula weeknum("8/27/2020",2). So 2 stands for Monday. Hence i would like to find the exact way in python.

Comment: Does your cycle start with Sunday = 0 or Saturday = 1

Comment: cycle starts from Monday

Comment: So `Monday = 2`, `Tuesday = 3`, `Wednesday = 4`, `Thursday = 5`, `Friday = 6`, `Saturday = 7`, and `Saturday = 8`?

Comment: Yes the sequence which you are showing is as per excel spreadsheet. However in python i need to start the cycle starting Monday.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of %V, try %u. Alternatively, %w will be Sunday through Saturday and give 0 through 6.

Use this link for more details: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

%u  :  ISO 8601 weekday as a decimal number where 1 is Monday. ->   1, 2, …, 7